# Android sign in key not working

Tags: android, keydown, onkeydown, android-keypad

I have created a login activity .In the login screen, the password editText comes with a keyboard that has "sign in" Key . When I press this key , the key board hides but no action takes place. I have overriden the onKeyDown() and assumed this key to be enter . But Still the login action does not take place

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
    {
        //your Action code
        if (DeviceUtil.isNetworkAvailable(LoginActivity.this)) {
            authenticate(muserName.getText().toString(),   mpwd.getText().toString());
        } else {
            showMessage("Network Not Available!");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Can anyone please suggest what I can do here?

Comment: did you set `onKeyListener` on your `edittext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `onKeyListener` to the view that's going to be focused when the key is pressed. For  instance, if you're view has an id of `password`, you'd do the following:

```
findViewById(R.id.password).setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            //Your code
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```